# Is the usage of was after the comma correct in this sentence

Tags: passive, perfect-tense

Is the usage of was after the comma correct in this sentence

Die Gesellschaft wird bald Pleite, was auf der Führung zurückzuführen ist.

Comment: Actually it should be '..auf die Führung..' In this usage 'was' is being used for starting a causal sentence. Sorry for my weird English right now I am a bit down.

Comment: Looks like machine translated. Message may be: »Der Staat ist bald pleite, was auf die Regierung zurückzuführen ist.«

Comment: Indeed. If the origin is english you should post it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the comma is correct. We have a subclause here which is separated from the main clause by comma.

Yet there are other mistakes in the sentence, correctly it would be:

> Die Gesellschaft wird bald pleite, was auf die Führung zurückzuführen ist.

Comment: I'd either say "ist bald pleite" or "wird bald pleite sein"

Comment: Or *geht bald pleite.*